# Pause or end and SKAction

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have an SKSpriteNode which is running an actionForever. This SKSpriteNode is changing the object on a collision the problem is that because the other action is running forever it will change back to that. Is there a way to stop an action?

```
   SKTexture* groundOverlay = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"layer-5"];
    groundOverlay.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;


    SKAction* moveOverlaySprite = [SKAction moveByX:-groundOverlay.size.width*2 y:0 duration:0.01 * groundOverlay.size.width*2];
    SKAction* resetOverlaySprite = [SKAction moveByX:groundOverlay.size.width*2 y:0 duration:0];
    moveOverlaySpritesForever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[moveOverlaySprite, resetOverlaySprite]]];

    for( int i = 0; i < 2 + self.frame.size.width; ++i ) {
        // Create the sprite
        sprite1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:groundOverlay];
        [sprite1 setScale:1.0];
        sprite1.position = CGPointMake(i * sprite1.size.width, sprite1.size.height / 2);
        [sprite1 runAction:moveOverlaySpritesForever withKey:@"bg2"];
        [self addChild:sprite1];
    }
```

Comment: Please post some code related to the SKAction object

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22037223/stop-skaction-that-repeatsforever-sprite-kit

Comment: I've added a code which is a moving background which is in the InitWithSize method. I would like to removeThisAction. How can i do this?

Comment: have you tried using `[sprite removeActionWithKey:@"bg2"];`?

Comment: Yep it does not work.

Comment: not even removeAllActions does work

Comment: Are you sure that you are calling `removeActionWithKey` on the same sprite instance that you added the action to?  Can you edit your question to show the code where you try to remove the action?  Is `sprite1` a local variable in the method or an instance variable for your object?