# How would I remove this function when the game is over?

Tags: swift

I have this function and I want to remove it once the game is over. I tried using removeActionWithKey but that doesn't seem to work. Is there another way I could remove it once the game is over?

```
 func doAction() {
    let generateCircles = SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.runBlock(self.circleRandom),
        SKAction.waitForDuration(1.5)])
    let endlessAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(generateCircles)
    runAction(endlessAction)
}


 if firstBody.categoryBitMask == HeroCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == RedCategory {

    //Tried to remove the func here but that doesn't work.     
    removeActionForKey("stop")
}


    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    touchingScreen = false

    if let touch = touches.first {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        if node.name == "start" {

            startGame.removeFromParent()

            //Calling the doAction func here once start button is pressed.

            let action = SKAction.runBlock(doAction)

            runAction(action, withKey: "stop")


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22037223/stop-skaction-that-repeatsforever-sprite-kit

Comment: I tried that func keeps runnin.

Comment: when you add the action you probably should set a key that you can then use to remove the action, like `runAction(endlessAction, withKey: "myKey1")`

Comment: I did that already. Look at the bottom of the code I put action and the key is "stop".

Comment: which action are you trying to remove again?

Comment: Im trying to remove the function doAction().

Comment: shouldn't you remove `endlessAction` too?

Comment: Yes I just tried what you said but it still calling the func.

Comment: Let me add more code to the op maybe Im doing something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: I updated the question can you take a look at it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `runAction(endlessAction)` with `runAction(endlessAction, withKey: "endlessAction1")`

then call

```
removeActionForKey("stop")
removeActionForKey("endlessAction1")
```

where you want it to stop.

Comment: I thought I had to stop just the function not the action inside the function.