# swift spritekit : How to stop a runBlock?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, removeall

How can I stop all actions from a runBlock:

```
func slideShowControl () {


    let noObject = SKSpriteNode()
    noObject.name = "noObject"

    addChild(noObject)



    let block = SKAction.runBlock({

        self.slideShow(1)
        print("slide01")

        self.runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(5), completion: {

            print("slide02")


        })

        self.runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(8), completion: {

            print("slide03")

        })

        ...

        self.runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(17), completion: {

            print("slide06")

        })

    })


    noObject.runAction(block, withKey: "stop")
```

self.slideShow(1) just present a button to send the key "stop", but the block continues to run and print. Is possible to stop this block?

```
noObject.removeActionForKey("stop")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop SKAction that RepeatsForever - Sprite Kit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22037223/stop-skaction-that-repeatsforever-sprite-kit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So you are naming an object "noObject" and an action "stop"? :)

Anyway, you should use a `group` and a few `sequence` actions.

### The idea

This code

```
self.runAction(SKAction.waitForDuration(5), completion: {
    print("slide02")
})
```

can also be written this way

```
let action1 = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(5), SKAction.runBlock { print("slide02") }])
```

### Solution

Given a sprite

```
let sprite = SKSpriteNode()
```

and 4 actions

```
let action0 = SKAction.runBlock { print("slide01") }
let action1 = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(5), SKAction.runBlock { print("slide02") }])
let action2 = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(8), SKAction.runBlock { print("slide03") }])
let action3 = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(6), SKAction.runBlock { print("slide06") }])
```

we can group the actions like this

```
let group = SKAction.group([action0, action1, action2, action3])
```

Now we can run the action with a key

```
sprite.runAction(group, withKey: "group")
```

and stop it

```
sprite.removeActionForKey("group")
```